# Can I create a theme for personal use in Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I have just started using Tumblr and I want to create a personalized blog/website for a special occasion (Birthday) in it. I am wondering if I can create a theme for personal use in Tumblr. Like may be I create a theme and do not need to make it public.

Can I do this in Tumblr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and No. Can't contribute a theme without making it public but you can deploy custom CSS.

Under the dashboard - advanced tab - enter custom CSS values to override everything. Their element identifiers are well defined and can be over-written easily.